# Python - Replacing Expressions in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

My function myfunction needs custom classes as an input. I defined a lot of custom classes. I want to call myfunction with every definition of my custom classes.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
from custom_lib import Class_0,Class_1,....Class_100

for i in range(101):
    myfunction(Class_i)
```

and replace the i in the for loop so the functions gets called with all classes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could investigate eval? but maybe best to rethink what you're trying to achieve? thats a lot of classes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `list` of all the classes, and use it in the `for`:

```
class_list = [Class_0,Class_1,....Class_100] # Write the classes instead of ....
for cl in class_list:
    myfunction(cl)
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import custom_lib
for cl in dir(custom_lib):
    if cl.startswith('Class_'):
        myfunction(getattr(custom_lib, cl))
```